# Python: Recursive generator skips values

Tags: python, recursion, generator, nested-lists

I've tried to create a *recursive* generator function in python that **flattens the nested lists**. It is for understanding purposes. Here is the code

```
def flat(list_x):
    try:
        for element in list_x:
            yield flat(element).next()
    except TypeError:
        yield list_x
```

So I only get a flattened list of the first elements of the nested lists.

```
l=[[1,2],[3,4]]
a=flat(l)
list(a)
[1,3]
```

**EDIT:** From what I've tested this is what actually happens on the inside. With the test list `l=[[1,2],[3,4]` which has sublist `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`. The first loop goes through each element of the main list, then recursive call to the generator makes it go into another *for* loop at which point for the first sublist it should do both:

```
for 1 in [1,2]:
    yield flat(1).next()
```

at which point TypeError would be raised and value 1 yielded

and

```
for 2 in [1,2]:
    yield flat(2).next()
```

at which point another TypeError exception should be raised and value 2 yielded but it does not do that, hence the title. I've tested this extensively this is exactly the behaviour, lists could be made longer or they can be nested deeper but it will always just give the first element of the nested list. Was kind of hoping to get the behind the curtains answer of why it does that, and functions written in exactly the same way do not.

So what I want to understand is why it skips other elements of the for loop. I can make a solution with functions doing basically the same thing. Here is the code:

```
def flat_f(list_x, result):
    try:
        for element in list_x:
            result.append(flat_f(element,result))
    except TypeError:
            return list_x
#removing None values generated by recursive function calls(probably there is a better way of doing this) 
    for index, number in enumerate(result):
        if item==None: del result[index]
```

So I am not sure why it doesn't work, have been banging my head on this for a few days, if anyone can explain why I would be very grateful.

Comment: In what fashion have you been "banging your head"?  You neglected to provide the diagnostic trace, especially where you're stuck.  In essence, you've dumped your program -- a short example, very nice -- but you don't seem to have tried to debug it.  Stick in a couple of strategic `print` calls to track execution and values.  I suspect that will show you where you've misconstrued what `next` will do.

Comment: Note that ``.next()`` is a Python2 generator method – Python3 uses ``next(...)`` (or ``.__next__()``). Since Python2 is EOL, please *strongly* consider to upgrade. Python2 also has various technical shortcomings (garbage collection, ...) that specifically affect generators.

Comment: @Prune I did that, I just didn't want to include that in the code here. In the example listed below, where `l=[[1,2],[3,4]]` it goes calls the generator twice and then for whatever reason it does not do the `for 2 in [1,2]` and just skips to the original for loop, that is `for element in list_x`, I perhaps should have explained that better.
@MisterMiyagi thanks for the advice, I am usually using python 3, I just wanted to understand why this specifically happens, because it is the same in python 3 if I use `yield next(flat(element))`.

Comment: Please edit this into your main question -- as you can see, comments do not format well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yield flat(element).next()` only yields the first value, and then you discard the rest of the nested list and move on to the next one. Use `yield from`.

```
def flat(list_x):
    for element in list_x:
        try:
            yield from flat(element)
        except TypeError:
            yield element
```

If you need to support Python 2, replace the `yield from` with a loop.

```
def flat(list_x):
    for element in list_x:
        try:
            i = iter(element)
        except TypeError:
            yield element
        else:
            for x in i:
                yield x
```

Comment: `yield from` is python3.3+ syntax, `.next` is python2, might just need a clarification

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. So basically it is the intended behaviour, to just yield the first value and skip the rest.